# If "For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction", why does a gun not injure the shooter's hand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

If "For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction", why does a gun not injure the shooter's hand?

Would not the "equal and opposite reaction" of firing a bullet be the kickback the shooter feels?  How can the kickback cause (little or) no injury, but the bullet cause great harm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a back reaction on the shooters arm. But since the gun is much heavier than the bullet, the velocity of the gun is much smaller.

This follows from momentum conservation, which states that the velocity of the gun is $v_g=v_b\frac{m_b}{m_g}$.

Next the energy of the gun is also absorbed by a larger impact area, than the bullet, lessening the effect even further.

Comment: I had figured the impact area had a lot to do with it, but I hadn't considered the gun being much heavier than the bullet.  That makes a lot of sense!

What about acceleration?  The bullet will accelerate as it leaves the barrel.  Would that make the kickback significantly less than the bullet's impact?

Comment: Hm, the force exerted of the handle onto the hand is the total timederivative of the momentum of the gun. Shouldn't the mass of the gun cancel?

Comment: @tonydo: Ah you are right. The force is indeed independent of the mass of the gun. And, the pressure on the hand as the revolver is recoiled only dependent on the (projected) surface area pressed against the hand. However, The recoil distance of the hand (as is stops the gun), depends on the Kinetic energy of the gun, which depends on the ratio of the masses of the gun and bullet. So would think that the weight of the gun does matter somewhat for the experience of the shooter.

Comment: Momentum is proportional to velocity, where as kinetic energy is proportional to the square of velocity. So for example is the gun's mass is 400 times the mass of the bullet, conservation of momentum says velocity of bullet is 400 times greater. However, the kinetic energy of the bullet will be 400 times the kinetic energy of the gun. (400^2 divided by 400)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like people watch too much TV around here.

Who says there is no injurious recoil?   [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fc_WamMBoRs), or just go to Youtube and search for "gun recoil".  Mostly you'll find rifle recoil videos, but there are some featuring handguns, such as the second vignette in [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2qmYDtshcE)  (The fourth vignette in that last video is quite troubling.)

Comment: I think that most people are going off of the idea that when used _properly_, there is little/no injury to the shooter.  I did find it interesting that most people referred to the impact on the shooter's hand.  In my mind (owning a rifle), I imagined an impact to the shoulder.   _____ I just re-read my own question.  I was the one that brought up the hand.  Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Because the bullet is very small compared to the handle of the gun. The bullet exerts a high pressure (Force per Area) and is able to pierce through skin.
The backreaction of the handle is distributed onto the whole hand.

Answer (score 1):

Think of force as the change in momentum with time 
Mathematically formalising this:
$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$$

$$p=mv$$
By conservation of momentum if the bullet leaves the barrel at some velocity (albeit quite high) comparatively the mass is incredibly small with respect to your hand 
So although the momentum imparted to your hand would be in the opposite direction but of equal magnitude as the bullet
Since the mass of the gun and your hand is so large the change in velocity of the gun and your hand would not be sufficient to injure your hand

This follows the conservation of momentum 
$$v_{g+h}=\frac{v_{b} m_{b}}{m_{g+h}}$$

---

I dare not say the change in velocity of your hand is small as you will note the recoil one experiences when he fires a gun is fairly significant and enough to throw an inexperienced gunner off their feet I.E when shooting a shotgun

Comment: It would be fair to say the change in velocity is small for the gun: compared to the sometimes supersonic bullet velocities, the few m/s that the weapon itself acquires is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this:

1. The momentum of the bullet and the momentum of the gun are distributed over different area. The recoil distributed over all the area of the gun's butt, while the bullet's momentum is applied to a much smaller area. Therefore momentum per unit square is much less in the case of the gun.
2. You need to include also the momentum of the gases that push the bullet. They carry away some of the momentum and thus can make the recoil less harmful.
3. In all modern guns there are special [systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_brake) that damp the recoil by increasing the time at which it is transferred to the shooter or by dissipating a part of it.